# rspec - getting "Locating textareas with '#text_field' is deprecated."

Tags: ruby, rspec, textarea

I have a test assertion:-

```
expect(browser.text_fields[2].id).to eq "new_user_email"
```

It passed but I am getting this deprecation warning message:

```
Locating textareas with '#text_field' is deprecated.  
Please, use '#textarea' method instead.
```

I tried changing the test to

```
expect(browser.textarea[2].id).to eq "new_user_email"
```

but got

```
undefined method `[]' for #<Watir::TextArea:0x00000001c128d8>
```

and I tried

```
expect(browser.textareas[2].id).to eq "new_user_email"
```

and get

```
 Failure/Error: expect(browser.textareas[2].id).to eq "new_user_email"

   expected: "new_user_email"
        got: ""
```

I looked at the source but it didn't help me:-

```
VALID_TEXT_FIELD_TAGS = %w[input textarea]

def tag_name_matches?(tag_name, _)
  VALID_TEXT_FIELD_TAGS.include?(tag_name)
end

def by_id
  el = super
  el if el and not NON_TEXT_TYPES.include? el.attribute(:type)
end

def validate_element(element)
  if element.tag_name.downcase == 'textarea'
    warn "Locating textareas with '#text_field' is deprecated. Please, use '#textarea' method instead."
  end
  super
end
```

How can I get rid of the deprecation warning?

Answer (score 1):

I hazard a guess that your page has multiple text fields and multiple text areas.

Your original code with `text_fields` grabs both text fields and text areas and puts them into the same collection. This is a bit surprising, and is probably why watir is deprecating that behavior.

Using `textarea` only returns a single object, not a collection. That is why `[]` is undefined.

Using `textareas` returns *only* text areas, not a combination of both. This text area is probably the first on the page, and you have another later on that has no id. If you didn't have multiple, I'd expect you'd get an error saying there was no such element.

I'd highly recommend not relying on the position of your elements; it tends to make your tests too brittle. Instead, you should use selectors (CSS or XPath) as appropriate. For example, you should be able to use something like

```
browser.textarea(id: 'new_user_email')
```